# What is the replacement for connect in Julia?

Tags: julia

```
julia> conn = connect(1234)

ERROR: UndefVarError: connect not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[1]:1
```

It's not working after update so is there any new keyword by which it's been replaced?

```
help?> connect
search: continue countlines count_ones

Couldn't find connect
Perhaps you meant convert, collect, const, count or conj
  No documentation found.

  Binding connect does not exist.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Julia version 0.7 is a handy tool when trying to port pre-existing code to julia 1.x: for all functions that have been deprecated in Julia 1.0.0, a warning is shown in julia 0.7.

In the specific case of `connect`:

```
shell$ julia-0.7.0               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  A fresh approach to technical computing
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?" for help, "]?" for Pkg help.
  | | | | | | |/ _  |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 0.7.0 (2018-08-08 06:46 UTC)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official http://julialang.org/ release
|__/                   |  x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

julia> connect
WARNING: Base.connect is deprecated: it has been moved to the standard library package `Sockets`.
Add `using Sockets` to your imports.
 in module Main
connect (generic function with 8 methods)
```

Following the information given in this message, `connect` should now be used as:

```
using Sockets
socket = connect(1234)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is working with Package Sockets 
so just use following to install this package:-

```
import Pkg;
Pkg.add("Sockets")
```

Now use it as follows

```
julia> using Sockets

julia> Sockets.connect(1234)
TCPSocket(RawFD(0x00000014) open, 0 bytes waiting)
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you encounter this kind of issues, I recommend using the docker images to quickly find the deprecation warnings (this is of course a general advise and not only applicable to Julia ;)

You can install [Docker](https://www.docker.com) easily on any Linux distribution and for Mac and Windows there are even GUI versions called [Docker Desktop](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop)

If you have Docker installed, you can use the `docker` command in the terminal to create containers from images, which are e.g. hosted on [DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com).

Here is a small example, first launching a Julia 1.0 container to check for `connect` and then trying Julia 0.7:

```
░ tgal@staticbox:~
░ 08:58:01 > docker run -it julia:1.0
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?" for help, "]?" for Pkg help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 1.0.5 (2019-09-09)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official https://julialang.org/ release
|__/                   |

julia> connect
ERROR: UndefVarError: connect not defined

julia>

░ tgal@staticbox:~ took 10s
░ 08:58:18 > docker run -it julia:0.7
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  A fresh approach to technical computing
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?" for help, "]?" for Pkg help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 0.7.0 (2018-08-08 06:46 UTC)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official http://julialang.org/ release
|__/                   |  x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

julia> connect
WARNING: Base.connect is deprecated: it has been moved to the standard library package `Sockets`.
Add `using Sockets` to your imports.
 in module Main
connect (generic function with 8 methods)
```

Comment: Thanks it really helped